# I can't get cookie from backend node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

I send a cookie to client side but i can't get
In my browser there is no cookies

auth.js:

```
export const Login = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      email: req.body.email,
    });
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User Not Found"));
    const CorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );
    if (!CorrectPassword)
      return next(createError(400, "Wrong password or email"));
    
    const token = jwt.sign({
        id: user._id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin
    },
    process.env.JWT_SEC
    
    )
    
    const {password, isAdmin, ...others} = user._doc
    res.cookie("access_token", token, {
      maxAge:900000,
      httpOnly:true,
      
    }).status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Login.jsx React:

```
    const handleClick = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(loginStart());
        try {
          const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/login", {
            email,
            password,
          });
          dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
          navigate("/");
        } catch (err) {
          dispatch(loginFailure());
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
```

This is my code

How to fix this?

Comment: `httpOnly:true` is the problem - ***[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)*** - note: you're not even trying to access the cookie in your client code, so why is it a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit secure option to be false.
secure: true is a recommended option. However, it requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure cookies:

```js
app.use(
    session({
        store: new MongoStore({
            mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
            url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
        }),
        secret: "mysecret-ssss",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
            sameSite: true,
            secure: false // in development 
        }
    })
);
```